# How to finish DB writing properly if app is finished while wiriting is not completed?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite

So Im trying to write a collection of objects to a DB and I do it as simple as:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        wishesDBTableHelper.saveWishesList(wishesList);
    }
}).start();
```

also I'd tried:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (!wishesDBTableHelper.saveWishesList(wishesList))
            Log.e(this,"Unable to save WishList to DB!");
        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

the wish writing methods are:

```
public boolean saveWishesList(List<Wish> wishesList) {
    boolean isErrorOccured = false;
    for (Wish wish : wishesList)
        if ( !save(wish) )
            isErrorOccured = true;
    return !isErrorOccured;
}

public boolean save(Wish wish) {
    boolean isErrorOccured = false;

    final ContentValues cvPairs = new ContentValues();
    fillCVPairs(cvPairs, wish);
    cvPairs.put(DBHelper.TABLE_WISHES_FIELD_ID, wish.id);

    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try {
        db = dbHelper.openWritableDB();
        synchronized (db){
            if (db.insertOrThrow(DBHelper.TABLE_WISHES, null, cvPairs) < 0)
                isErrorOccured = true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        isErrorOccured = true;
    } finally{
        if (db!=null)
            dbHelper.closeWritableDB();
    }

    return !isErrorOccured;
}
```

and SQLiteHelper:

```
private AtomicInteger mOpenCounter = new AtomicInteger();
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public SQLiteDatabase openWritableDB() {
    if(mOpenCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
        // Opening new database
        mDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return mDatabase;
}

public void closeWritableDB() {
    if(mOpenCounter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
        // Closing database
        mDatabase.close();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine and thread writes wishes to DB. But the problem is this operation requires some time to be completed and if user leaves an app while its not done app crashes saying:

> E/AndroidRuntime(25240): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-38
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25240): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25240):  at
>   java.util.LinkedList$LinkIterator.next(LinkedList.java:124)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25240):  at
>   x.y.z.db.WishesDBTableHelper.saveWishesList(WishesDBTableHelper.java:31)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25240):  at
>   x.y.z.db.WishesParser$1.run(WishesParser.java:77)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25240):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

So how to avoid that issue or how to let thread to continue its job till completion on app exit?

Comment: Notice the ConcurrentModificationException from ListIterator. Your list was modified when your iterator was iterating.

Comment: thanx. The `wishesDBTableHelper.saveWishesList(new LinkedList<Wish>(wishesList))` in `Runnable` fixed the issue.